# Image render in React from JSON

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, image

I'm am trying to display a set of images from a JSON file. I can console.log all the data from the JSON but when I try to access just a single field I get undefined. The JSON file is in the public folder. It is currently displaying the torn img logo and the alt text.

Example of JSON

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "make": "Alfo Romeo",
    "model": "8C Spider",
    "year": "2008",
    "top-speed": "180 MPH",
    "image": "https://www.supercars.net/blog/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/1087779-1024.jpg",
    "price": "$299,000"
}
```

I am currently mapping over the data to return just the image. Later I will add an onClick that will display the rest of the data

My code

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"
import axios from 'axios'

export default function HomePage () {
    const [list, setList] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get('./cars.json')
            .then((res) => {
                setList(res.data)
            })
    }, [])
    console.log(list) //this will display all JSON. If I try to console.log(list.any other field) it returns undefined

    return (
        <div className="homepage">
            <h1>Auto Collection</h1>
            <div className="carImages">
                <ul>
                    {list.map(car => 
                        <img src={list.image} alt='pic'/>
                    )}
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Typo?  You're trying to show `list.image`, which is indeed `undefined`.  You meant to use `car.image`.

Comment: Its always the little things. That worked. I appreciate you!